# Is it possible to get intellisense to work with Geb page objects?

Tags: groovy, geb

I am guessing this is more of a groovy issue due to the geb implementation, but I'm wondering if there is any way to get intellisense to work with the geb page objects.  I am also new to Java/Groovy (primarily C# development in the past) so there could be some things I'm just not quite understanding.  I'm using Intellij, but I'd be happy if there is any IDE that could give me what I wanted.

As far as I can tell, Geb's implementation is that they have a Browser Class with a Page property and any methods or properties that are executed without the context of a specific Page instance will at runtime trigger a MissingMethod or MissingProperty exception, which Geb handles and re-routes to a corresponding method or property in the Page class that is currently set via the Page property in the Browser Class.

What this means for development is that when we're creating test cases, the IDE is unaware of which page instance is the current Browser Page property, thus no intellisense.

We experimented with creating instances of the pages and explicitly calling them, and also making our helper functions within the page classes static, both of which led to other issues.

For our shop, this is pretty much a deal breaker, but before we give up I wanted to see if any Geb or Groovy experts could offer some advice on how to get intellisense working, or could give us an indication of whether it is even possible.

EDIT: I found within the geb documentation a section on Strong Typing and IDE support that looked promising: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/ide-and-typing.html#ide_support however, the examples provided fail.  I pasted the example directly from geb documentation below, with comments showing where/why it fails:

```
HomePage homePage = browser.to HomePage //browser.to returns null, so this fails
homePage.loginButton.click()

LoginPage loginPage = browser.at LoginPage //browser.at returns boolean so this fails
SecurePage securePage = loginPage.login("user1", "password1")

//The only thing that I got to work, which seems messy is:
browser.to HomePage
HomePage homePage = browser.page
homePage.loginButton.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... So, I had an old version of Geb somehow being pulled from my gradle cache.  After fixing that problem and actually using Geb 0.9.2, the documented usage worked correctly: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/ide-and-typing.html#ide_support